# Report on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, reports-api

Please let me know how the below code needs to be changed to get a report to appear on the visualforce page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="ReportController">
{   
  "completionDate" : null,   
  "hasDetailRows" : true,   
  "id" : "00O2F000000O8oIUAS",
  "ownerId" : "00561000000faoYAAQ",   
  "queryable" : false,   
  "requestDate" : "2017-11-7T16:05:43Z",   
  "status" : "New",   
  "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/analytics/reports/00O2F000000O8oIUAS/instances/00561000000faoYAAQ"
}

</apex:page>
```

Comment: While you can display charts on a Visualforce page, there is no standard way to display a report on the page.  You could try this person's approach which uses JQuery and jsforce:  http://sfdcintegration.blogspot.com/2015/10/display-reports-in-visualforce-page.html

Comment: The link shows how to add fields to a table, but not to place a full report in a Visualforce page. So far I have not seen that this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

First I looked into a frame and learned this is no longer supported. Then, I tried to add the fields via Visualforce but got stuck on adding totals, was not able to get to work. Then I setup an oauth2 api connection and this is where I am currently and I got the code that was modified in the above question. Thanks!